# Use keywords in Facebook Audience Network

Tags: facebook-audience-network

I would like to tell FAN the keywords that are relevant to the current screen. In Google Admob I have this options:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/api/reference/Classes/GADRequest#/c:objc(cs)GADRequest(py)keywords

I cannot find this option anywhere in the FAN docs or APIs.

Any ideas?